# Why can't I connect to localhost:3000 in any browser?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs3

***UPDATE APPENDED***

I am unable to connect to `localhost:3000` in any of the four browsers I've tried, including current versions of Chrome, Bravo, Edge and Opera. I inevitably get the message: `localhost refused to connect`.

The other relevant bit of the message is: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I created a *Vuetify 3* app using *Vue 3* and the current version of *Visual Studio Code*. There were no errors from creating the app. Executing `http://localhost:3000` is *supposed* to make the default splash screen display in Chrome but, instead, I get the error message I mentioned above.

I'm running Windows 10 Home, version 22H2. I've used localhost successfully many times over several years on this same laptop so I'm baffled about what could be wrong.

I don't see any reason why this would be relevant but the timing is suspicious. Yesterday, I had an issue yesterday with copy and paste in Windows: `CTRL-C` simply wouldn't copy anything to the clipboard. I eventually resolved that by running `sfc /scannow`. Its report indicated that it had fixed some corrupted files. Is there any chance that this somehow messed up localhost (or that the issue which corrupted the clipboard also impacted localhost somehow)?

Can anyone suggest a solution?

**Update:**
With respect to Yoduh's question, I created the app with Visual Studio Code (current version). I opened a terminal, changed directory to `c:\Vue`, executed `npm create vuetify`, gave the project the name `the-vuetify-course2`, selected "Basic" (i.e. just Vue and VueRouter), said "Yes" to Typescript, and chose `npm` as the package manager. The resulting message said the project had been created successfully. Here is the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "the-vuetify-course2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint . --fix --ignore-path .gitignore"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "7.0.96",
    "core-js": "^3.29.0",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/types": "^7.21.4",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.0",
    "unplugin-fonts": "^1.0.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.0",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use Vue 3.x and Vuetify 3.x.

For what it's worth, I tried executing `npm run dev` from the project directory but got this:

```
> the-vuetify-course2@0.0.0 dev
> vite

'vite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,      
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Vue 3, but could you please add how you set up the add in case there might be a problem there?

Comment: Did you check that a local web server is listenning on port 3000 and that this port is open in the firewall? Maybe some configurations have been reset when you fixed Windows.

Comment: @AlanBagel - I don't understand your question, especially "set up the add".

Comment: @Eric - I don't remember how to do that. Can you point me to some instructions? I'm not sure if you're talking about making changes to my hosts file - which I haven't touched in years - or altering browser or firewall settings. I can't find  any relevant  browser settings in Chrome. I have determined that my firewall is on and how to add an app to it but I don't know WHICH app to let through so that this works correctly.

Comment: localhost won't display your app unless you run the local development server which usually involves running a command, e.g. `npm run dev` (or possibly `npm run serve`).  The result of the successful command will also tell you if the app is running on localhost:3000 or some other port.  this is also assuming you have an environment set up for local server like with vite or webpack.  if you're not familiar with anything I've said, just post the content of your package.json file if you have one and/or at least describe how you initially created the app.

Comment: @Henry, as a last resort, you may uninstall and reinstall, or repair, Visual Studio Code. It should then configure the firewall again. The local web server (part of Visual Studio Code) should be running and listenning on port 3000 when Visual Studio Code is launched.

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` there should be a reason. chrome won't load http site without additional settings... use https

Comment: @BorisMaslennikov - I tried https://localhost:3000 just now but got the exact same error.

Comment: @BorisMaslennikov - I used https to try localhost but the https part is hidden in my previous comment.

Comment: are you using valid certificate for https? can you try changing port number? can you try to run your code on different pc?

Comment: @BorisMaslennikov - I've never knowingly installed a certificate anywhere and my localhost has been working fine for years, including a few weeks back when I last accessed it. I don't know how to redirect VSCode to use a port other than 3000. I will try executing my code on my backup laptop but I'll need to install a bunch of stuff and transfer a lot of files before I can see if that works. I'll start on that now.

Comment: browser won't load the page if youre using https without a cert... changing port - https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options

I would also try to create basic vue project using `npm create vue@latest` then install vuetify in it using vuetify guide.